# How to send unencrypted e-mail in 2018?

Tags: email, encryption, exchange, tls, mailbox

For test purpose I need to send an unencrypted message to my corporate mailbox from the outside, but I find it almost impossible to find a mailbox provider who gives that option.

Any ideas?

Best Regards,
Luke

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean under term of "unencrypted message"? Generally most emails are  "unencrypted message" nowadays except those who using S/MIME of GPG encryption. Connection between servers over secure TLS channel isn't encryption but simply prevent man-in-a-middle attack, but owner of email servers can see emails as plain unencrypted text.

Comment: I agree with Alex here. It is actually taking quite a bit of steps to setup encrypted message sending. Most if not all email traffic I see in my outlook is unencrypted. When a message is encrypted, it will show a seal icon on the message itself.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I need to analyze a header of a message sent without TLS to our servers with Opportunistic TLS option enabled.

Comment: You should edit your message to reflect that then.

Comment: If "Opportunistic TLS option" is enabled on your corporate server then by default practically any MTA that would talk to your server will take advantage to switch conversation over encrypted channel. If you want to experiment on this, you can get any cheapest VPS for 2-3 bucks, setup there `postfix` and unset smtp client settings that allows SSL/TLS connections

Answer (score 1):

For very valid security reasons, most public mail servers will probably refuse to connect anywhere without SSL/TSL. You can either set up your own test server or try to connect to your corporate mailbox directly. Both of that will only be possible, if your corporate mailbox accepts unencrypted and not authenticated traffic (which it should not, under normal circumstances, as this invites spam and worse).

There are detailed tutorials on the web on how to connect to an SMTP Server via telnet ([example](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/mail-flow/test-smtp-with-telnet)).

Answer (score 1):

But please note that I don't think we're answering the OP's actual question here.  He is asking about sending an encrypted *email,* not whether-or-not the *network connection to the email server* is encrypted.

I sincerely believe that the OP should direct his question to the IT staff at his company.  There are many, many ways to set up "corporate e-mail" and to determine whether (and if so, how) messages can be sent to/from the outside world.  Likewise, messages can be "always encrypted" or "always signed," and so on.  Frankly, "we can't guess how your employer chose to set things up," and the devil is in these details.  But, your employer's IT staff *would* be able to help you accomplish this.